# How to modify directives isolated scope variable in controller, while still keeping it isolated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with isolated scope. I am modifying one of the variables passed from the parent controller in the controller of the directive. The issue I'm running into is that when I use multiple instances of this directive (with different `options` and `model`) on the same view, the `options` object does not remain unique to each instance of the directive. Instead, it becomes a shared variable and all the instances of the directive use the same `options` object.

So if I had used them in my view like below, with `optionsA.isFlagOn = true` and `optionsB.isFlagOn = false`

```
<my-directive model="modelA" options="optionsA">
<my-directive model="modelB" options="optionsB">
```

Directive with `modelB` loads with the `optionsA`.

How do I keep `options` unique while modifying it for each specific instance?

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  template = '<h3><span ng-bind="model.title"><h3><p><span ng-bind="options"></span></p>';
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
       model: "=",
       options: "=?" //A JSON object
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.options = $scope.options || {};
      //A function that sets default values if no options object passed
      ensureDefaultOptions($scope);

      //now based on some of the options passed in, I modify a property in the options object
      if ($scope.options.isFlagOn)
        $scope.options.thisProp = true;
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      let content = $compile(template)(scope);
      element.append(content);
    }
  };
}
```

**Edit:** I solved my issue. My solution is posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the bindToController property of Angular directive available in 1.4x or higher.

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    template = '<h3><span ng-bind="vm.model.title"><h3><p><span ng-bind="myOptions"></span></p>';
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      bindToController: {
        model: "=",
        options: "=?" //A JSON object
      },
      scope: {},
      controller: function() {
        var vm = this;

        //a function that handles modifying options
        vm.setOptions = function(options){
          let newOptions = {};
          angular.copy(options, newOptions);

          // modify newOptions here

          return newOptions;
        }

      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

         ensureDefaultOptions(scope.vm);

         scope.myOptions = scope.vm.setOptions(scope.vm.options);

         let content = $compile(template)(scope);
         element.append(content);
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change it to you one-way bindings with:

```
scope: {
       model: "=",
       options: "<?" //A JSON object
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that works. It is not that the two way binding that screws up the directive scope. I am suspecting the issue is arising because I'm modifying the isolated scope variable in the directive controller, which is shared across  all instances of the directive.

Comment: OIC, then I don't think you want to inject $scope into your directive controller. scope.options should refer to the isolate scope.

Comment: IOW, $scope.options = $scope.options should probably be angular.extend(scope.options,$scope.options)

Answer (score 0):

Your directive should make a copy of passed in options combined with defaults, so each directive instance have its own option object.

You can achieve that easily by using `extend`

```
var defaultOptions = { a:1, b:2, c:3 };
var options = angular.extend(defaultOption, $scope.options);
// then use options everywhere
```

Note that this will only be done once during init, so if your options come from controller asynchronously, you'll need extra handling.